# How to use external data source (text file) for robot framework data-driven test?

Tags: robotframework, data-driven-tests

Based on the example below. 

 - Is it possible to put testcases part in a text file? 

 - How?

-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
*** settings ***
    Test Setup 
    Go to url
    Test Teardown CLose Browser
    Test Template Valid input
    Library Selenium2Library

*** variables ***
    ${URL} some url
    ${BROWSER}firefox

*** testcases ***  NAME AGE GENDER  SELECTEDGENDER   CHECKBOX
    valid name Ringo 20 Male entry.351010933  entry.1887354367
    Maximum name Paul McCartney 21 Male entry.351010933 entry.1887354367
    Minimum name John 22Male entry.351010933    entry.175266393

*** keywords ***
Valid input
 [Arguments]${NAME}${AGE}${GENDER}${SELECTEDGENDER}    ${CHECKBOX}
    Input Textid=entry_1563791636${NAME}
    Input Textid=entry_930637752${AGE}
    Select Radio Button${SELECTEDGENDER}${GENDER}
    Click Buttonid=ss-submit
    Select Checkbox${CHECKBOX}
    Click Buttonid=ss-submit


    Go to url
    Open Browser${URL}${BROWSER}
```

Comment: You aren't formatting the code properly, making the question hard to read.

Comment: I'm sorry for that one, but nonetheless I've modified the code formatting I hope more readable now. Thanks.